# How to rewrite url in htaccess without redirecting on localhost?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to ask my question again and explain it the best I can.

I am running WAMP on windows 10. Apache version 2.4.18. My project is in `www` folder named `hoidja.ee`. `mod_rewrite` is enabled, `AllowOverride`is set to All.

Inside that folder I have `.htaccess` file, where I am trying to accomplish rewrite without redirect and it does not work at all. I know the `.htaccess` file is working, since I can rewrite `index.php` to `/home/` for example and it is working perfectly fine.

I have a page with all the users listing. You can click on the user, and it will take you to a url:

`http://localhost/Hoidja.ee/hoidja.php?user_id=94&username=John`

How I would like this to show is

```
http://localhost/Hoidja.ee/user/John
```

without any redirection.

What I have tried:

```
#tried first with only user_id
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user_id=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^hoidja\.php$ /user/%1? [L]
```

This gave me 404 that /user/94 doesn't exist.

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ hoidja.php?user_id=$1&username=$2 [QSA]
```

This doesn't do anything visually. If I enter `http://localhost/Hoidja.ee/user/94/John` in the url manually, it goes to that page and shows the user data, but if I enter the original url it does not rewrite it. I am using `<base>` as well.

I have tried all the possible ways but nothing seems to work. How can I accomplish the url rewrite?

Comment: Using _both_, a user ID and a user name does not really make sense, it only makes things more complex and ambiguous...

Comment: @arkascha that is true. I am using the user_id to pull data from database, but I would like to display username in the url

Comment: Ok, nothing against displaying the name (whyever). But then you don't have to rewrite it or consider it during the rewrite, do you?

Comment: @arkascha you are correct. I dont have to consider it during rewrite, I would just like to show the name in the url. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the 404 error because you are rewriting to a non-existent path **/user/94** .you will need to redirect **/hoidja.php?user_id=** to  **/user/94** and then rewrite **/user/94** back to the real location.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user_id=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule hoidja\.php$ /hoidja.ee/user/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(?:hoidja\.ee/)?user/(.+)$ /hoidja.ee/hoidja.php?user_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried it and indeed it rewrites the url not. But it gives me this now:  http://localhost/user/83 so it goes to the localhost folder, not the initial one

Comment: yes. it does work now. tell me, like I said in my question: can I show the username instead of the user_id? So i have to parameters in the url. Is that possible as well? so the url will look like this in the end: http://localhost/Hoidja.ee/user/John

Comment: No, that's not possible. You do need id in your slug in order to find the user information.

Comment: So what would be the best option to display the username instead of the user_id but still get the relevant information? like facebook has /facebook.com/user/john.doe

Comment: It depends on how you are extracting data from database. if you are getting user information using **username** column and the  url to  php file is http://example.com/user.php?username=foobar then,yes it it is possible and the url can be rewritten to http://example.com/user/foobar .

Comment: At the moment i am using user_id. Can I hide the user_id?

Comment: anyway with your help I was able to achieve what I wanted. thanks man!